# inserting and updating on one button click

Tags: c#

how do l make my code below to insert into disposal table and delete from issues table on one button click.for the mean time its only deleting

```
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string con = "";
con = "delete from issue where Serial_Number ='" + serialNumber_txt.Text + " '";
con  = "insert into disposal (Serial_Number,Asset_Class,Asset_Code,Asset_Description,Model_Number,Engine_Number,PRB_Number,Quantity,From_dipo,Date_of_Dispo) values ('" + serialNumber_txt.Text + "','" + assetClass_txt.Text + "','" + assetCode_txt.Text + "','" + assetDesrip_txt.Text + "','" + modelNumber_txt.Text + "','" + engineNumber_txt.Text + "','" + prgNumber_txt.Text + "','" + quantity_txt.Text + "','" + from1.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker3.Text + "');";
command.CommandText = con;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Disposal was successful");
from1.Clear();
quantity_txt.Clear();
engineNumber_txt.Clear();
serialNumber_txt.Clear();
modelNumber_txt.Clear();
assetDesrip_txt.Clear();
assetCode_txt.Clear();
assetClass_txt.Clear();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: You need to execute 2 separate queries. If you need to ensure that both happen (without one failing) then use a transaction. Also, your code is overwriting the first query when you assign the second to the same variable (`con`)... oh, and look into parameterizing your queries to avoid SQL Injection Attacks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two diff vars for each query and Exececute both:

```
query1 = "delete from issue where Serial_Number ='" + serialNumber_txt.Text + " '";
query2 = "insert into disposal (Serial_Number,Asset_Class,Asset_Code,Asset_Description,Model_Number,Engine_Number,PRB_Number,Quantity,From_dipo,Date_of_Dispo) values ('" + serialNumber_txt.Text + "','" + assetClass_txt.Text + "','" + assetCode_txt.Text + "','" + assetDesrip_txt.Text + "','" + modelNumber_txt.Text + "','" + engineNumber_txt.Text + "','" + prgNumber_txt.Text + "','" + quantity_txt.Text + "','" + from1.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker3.Text + "');";
command.CommandText = query1;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.CommandText = query2;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  as commented, e.g:

```
 query1 = "delete from issue where Serial_Number =@param";
 command.CommandText = query1;
 command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@param",serialNumber_txt.Text );
```

Comment: Good addition on the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a less convoluted, more DRY (don't repeat yourself) solution, try something like this :

Define a method to execute multiple queries, like this :

```
public void executeQuery(string[] queries)
{
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    foreach(string query in queries)
    {
      string con = query;
      command.CommandText = con;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.close();
}
```

... now, you can do this :

```
executeQuery(
    new string[] 
        {"delete from issue where Serial_Number ='" + serialNumber_txt.Text + " '", 
         "insert into disposal (Serial_Number,Asset_Class,Asset_Code,Asset_Description,Model_Number,Engine_Number,PRB_Number,Quantity,From_dipo,Date_of_Dispo) values ('" + serialNumber_txt.Text + "','" + assetClass_txt.Text + "','" + assetCode_txt.Text + "','" + assetDesrip_txt.Text + "','" + modelNumber_txt.Text + "','" + engineNumber_txt.Text + "','" + prgNumber_txt.Text + "','" + quantity_txt.Text + "','" + from1.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker3.Text + "');"
        }
    );
```

Comment: thanx guys this is powerful you have add light into my path